# Clear radiogroup from another radiogroup in Android

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, oncheckedchanged

I have two radio groups A and B..

If any one of the radio button in A is pressed, the checked button (if any) on B should be cleared, and vice-versa..

Also I need to show the value of **select** in **selected**.

I have implemented something like this.

```
private EditText selected;
private int select = 0;
private RadioGroup Arow;
private RadioGroup Brow;
```

After implementing findViewById..

```
Arow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(AListener);
Brow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(BListener);
```

Listener of Arow:

```
OnCheckedChangeListener AListener= new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.one:
            select = 1;
            break;

        case R.id.two:
            select = 2;
            break;

        case R.id.three:
            select = 3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if(select > 0){
            selected.setText(""+ select );
        }
        Arow.clearCheck();  // point 1
    }
};
```

Listener of Brow:

```
OnCheckedChangeListener BListener= new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {

        case R.id.four:
            select = 4;
            break;
        case R.id.five:
            select = 5;
            break;
        case R.id.six:
            select = 6;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if( select > 0){
            selected.setText(""+ select );
        }
        Brow.clearCheck();  // point 2
    }
};
```

The problem is the above code is crashing, if I comment the above point 1 and point 2, the code is working but radio button is not cleared if I happen to select buttons from both A and B, though the select value is properly shown in the selected.

Edit: Logcat

```
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:913)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:103)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:182)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:332)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:176)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6263)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6161)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6708)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3783)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3641)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:94)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3616)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:232)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:203)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:234)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:203)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:234)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:203)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:234)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:203)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:234)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:203)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.xerox.ts.ops.hsd.activity.DemoActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(DemoActivity.java:234)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
01-13 15:35:05.886: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.widget.RadioG
```

Comment: can we see your logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel there must be infinite loop as clearCheck will be again trigerring the onCheckChanged event of other radioGroup.And this is causing stackOverflow error.

Lets assume there are 2 RadioGroup A and B. And you have onCheckListener for both. So when you are calling A.clearCheck() inside B check event, then all Checks of A are getting removed, which results in call to A onCheckChanged Listener. And inside A onCheckChanged Listener, again you have B.clearCheck(). so this repeats again and again.
 Please try this and let me know if it works:

```
Brow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
Brow.clearCheck();
Brow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(BListener);

Arow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
Arow.clearCheck();
Arow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(AListener);
```

Comment: Your code is working. But could you please explain thoroughly how did it went to infinite loop?

Comment: Now I got it.. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad. Happy Coding :)